# Position mat-menu on top of the trigger in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Hi i would like to position the mat-menu on top of the menu trigger. Please find my code below

```
<button (mouseover)="createMenuTrigger.openMenu() #createMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor="createPlan"> OnHover </button>


<mat-menu #createPlan="matMenu">
   <button>Menu1</button>
   <button>Menu2</button
</mat-menu>
```

While running the above code the menu panel is showing bottom or top of the trigger. But it should open on top of the trigger.

Current Working Menu position:
[Menu is opening on top or below the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR6G8.png)

Expected Menu panel:
[Menu panel should show on top the trigger 'onHover' button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuojE.png)

Please help me to resolve this UI change. I didnt get any valid solution for this change. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10):

You can "play" with the properties xPosition and yPosition, see  [MenuPositionX and menuPositionY](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MenuPositionX)

e.g.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" yPosition="above" xPosition="before">
```

Show the menú on top and on the left **if there're enougth space**.

You can also add class to the mat-menu using classPane

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="myMenu">
```

And add **in styles.css**,e.g. (*)

```
{
   .mat-menu-panel.myMenu {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

(*) You need add the class in a .css general to all the aplication, you can not add the class in the component.css also you use [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) (this make that all the .css in your component is applied to all the aplication). The reason is that a mat-menu create the menu in a cdk-overlay that not belong to the component

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[overlapTrigger]="false"` in the mat menu like below:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false"><mat-menu>
```

FIR : https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/menu/

Answer (score 0):

If by "on top of" the trigger you mean above it in the Y dimension, you can use `yPosition="above"` as Eliseo writes. If instead you mean you want the menu above the trigger in the Z dimension (in other words, covering the trigger) you'll want to take PaperInFlames' suggestion but set the `overlapTrigger` to `true`:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="true"><mat-menu>
```